# Derivative of spacetime coordinates with respect to themselves

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

If we do a derivative of spacetime in vector form with respect to itself, the result is delta tensor as the following
$$\dfrac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} = \delta^\alpha_\beta$$
but if we take the derivative of spacetime in one-form with respect to vector form, is the result will be delta tensor also?
$$\dfrac{\partial x_\alpha}{\partial x^\beta} \overset{?}{=} \delta_{\alpha \beta}$$
and if true, please say why?

Comment: Hint: act on $\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}$ with the metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general relativity, the coordinates $x^\mu$ of an event are not the components of a vector because position vectors don't exist. Therefore, it makes no sense to talk about lowering its index. The object $x_\mu$ is not defined.

However, in special relativity, $x^\mu$ is a four-vector so we can lower its index using
$$x_\mu \equiv \eta_{\mu\nu} x^\nu$$
and its derivative can then be taken easily.